# storing select results in an array

Tags: python, list, sqlite, select, store

I am using python sqlite to search on specific match in a certain column, once found a match, need to store the other columns' values in a python variables for further use.
what I can't do is to store the data from the select query in list

```py
for z in range(0,y):
    for m,n in cr.execute ("select English,Tagger from POS where Arabic=?",(x[z],)):
        h[z]=m
        f[z]=n
```

both m and n variables returning correct values in each iteration in the for loop but I can't store them in both h and f for further use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please describe the problem in more detail.

- What is the error that you get?
- Did you declared h, f variables as list of length y before you attempt to write into the list? - eg. h = [None] * z
- Or you can use dict h = {} and than h[z] = m
- Or if you don't need to know the z value just append to empty list - eg. h = [] and h.append(m)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure if `h` and `f` are list objects, but let's say it is. Because it seems that you're already appending the results to your list, you could do this:

```py
h = []
f = []
for z in range(0, y):
    for m,n in cr.execute ("select English,Tagger from POS where Arabic=?",(x[z],)):
        h.append(m)
        f.append(n)
```